# Can you get the final value from an animation before that animation has completed?

Tags: c#, wpf, doubleanimation

Say I start a four-second `DoubleAnimation` on the `Canvas.Left` property of a control that animates the value from its current value to 100 and that animation was started by calling `BeginAnimation` on that control in code-behind.

```
void Animate(Control someControlOnCanvas, int newX){

    var canvasLeftAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    canvasLeftAnimation.To = newX;
    canvasLeftAnimation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
    canvasLeftAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
    canvasLeftAnimation.Completed += (s, e) => {
        Canvas.SetLeft(targetButton, x);
    };

    someControlOnCanvas.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, canvasLeftAnimation);
}

Animate(somethingToMove, 100);
```

Say half-way through that animation--at the two-second mark--I need to cancel the current animation and start a new one with a new `To` position (the `From` position would be wherever it is right now) that's 100 past where the first animation *would* end (i.e. not where it currently is at 50, but where it's supposed to be, which is 100, so adding another 100 would yield a new target of 200.)

If I try getting the current Left value, it's the animated value of 50. If I try getting the base value, it's where the animation started, which is zero since it's not officially updated until the completion handler fires.

So outside of manually adding a variable to track where things should be, how can I start a new animation that says 'Go to the original end, plus 100?'

My thoughts are:

1. Get the existing/current animation
2. Get it's `To` value
3. Start a new animation with the previous animation's `To` value, plus 100

What I'm stuck on is getting #1.

...or am I going about this all wrong?